# Java-Stream - Transforming List to a nested Map

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream, refactoring, collectors

How can I simplify the following code? Can it be written as a single stream-statement?

*Clarification:* multiple `id` of branch can correspond to the same `appName`

*My code:*

```
Map<String, Map<Long, BranchSession>> sessions = new HashMap<>();

Map<String, Map<Long, List<Branch>>> map = branches.stream()
   .collect(
      Collectors.groupingBy(
         Branch::getAppName,
         Collectors.groupingBy(Branch::getId)
   ));

map.forEach((key, value) -> {
    Map<Long, BranchSession> bs = new HashMap<>();
    value.keySet().forEach(bId -> {
    List<Branch> list = value.get(bId);
    if (list.size() > 0)
       bs.put(bId, new BranchSession(value.get(bId).get(0)));
    });
    sessions.put(key, bs);
});
```

Comment: Yes multiple `id` correspond to the same appName

Comment: Show some test cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that there could be multiple `id` that correspond to the same `appName` (otherwise creating such a nested map is unnecessary, if each `appName` corresponds to a single unique `id` you can create two separate maps: *branchSession by id* `Map<Long, BranchSession>` and *branchSession by name* `Map<String, BranchSession>` which would be more convenient).

If my assumption is correct, you can apply *collector* `toMap` as the downstream of `groupingBy`:

```
Map<String, Map<Long, BranchSession>> branchSessionByIdAndByName = branches.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Branch::getAppName,
            Collectors.toMap(
                Branch::getId,
                branch -> new BranchSession(branch.getId())
            )
    ));
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/tzT)